# Starting apache Solr 5.3 in windows

Tags: solr

I am using solr4 in tomcat. Now i am planning to migrate it to Solr 5.3 , i tried to start the server using **solr start** . But i got the below exception

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot read file:  solr-5.3.0\solr-5.3.
0\server\modules\http.mod
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerModule(Modules.java:549)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerAll(Modules.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:111)
```

I cant see any stacktrace in the console. except the below error message

**ERROR: Solr at http://localhost:8983/solr did not come online within 30 seconds!**

i think there might be some basic configuration i am missing , please help .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Post+Tool#PostTool-Windows

Comment: Have you got any solution for this as I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Check your java version, it has to be 1.7 minimum for Solr 5.3
Check the logs at solr_folder/server/logs, the cause will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply stopping the server  and then restarting it helped:

```
D:\Apache Solr\solr-6.6.0\bin>solr.cmd stop -all
Stopping Solr process 8072 running on port 8983
```